# My.settings\ settings.settings keep getting a bad connection with the IDE (Visual studio 2019 community)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

I was working on a project that uses my.settings to save some data, but then I made a backup of the project and Factory reset my computer due to low space. I installed Visual studio like normally but now I have problems with my IDE. I continued to work on the previous project but now when I add new settings in My.settings in the designer I get an error stating(The file might be corrupt or contain invalid XML) but then continues to save the new data to the File?? but when I use My.Setttings in my program I get a huge error and the program continues to compile and work except none of the My.settings code i have in the project work dont work??

I got the problems As soon as the new IDE was installed on my Freshly Reset Computer and the error Always appears when I enter new My.settings values or Run the Program.

The Errors I get:

**When I enter new Settings:**

> An error occurred while saving values to the app.config file. The file
> might be corrupted or contain invalid XML.

**When I run the Code/program:**

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration
> system failed to initialize
>
> —> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized
> configuration section system.diagnostics. (D:! Random Work in
> progress\Game Save Duplicator\Game Save
> Duplicator\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Game Save Duplicator.dll.config
> line 8)
>
> at
> System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean
> ignoreLocal)
>
> at
> System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors
> schemaErrors)
>
> at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfInitErrors()
>
> at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String
> configKey)
>
> — End of inner exception stack trace —
>
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
>
> at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(String
> sectionName)
>
> at System.Configuration.ClientSettingsStore.ReadSettings(String
> sectionName, Boolean isUserScoped)
>
> at
> System.Configuration.LocalFileSettingsProvider.GetPropertyValues(SettingsContext
> context, SettingsPropertyCollection properties)
>
> at
> System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertiesFromProvider(SettingsProvider
> provider)
>
> at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.GetPropertyValueByName(String
> propertyName)
>
> at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.get_Item(String propertyName)
>
> at
> System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.GetPropertyValue(String
> propertyName)
>
> at System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.get_Item(String
> propertyName)
>
> at Game_Save_Duplicator.My.MySettings.get_DesFol() in D:! Random Work
> in progress\Game Save Duplicator\Game Save Duplicator\My
> Project\Settings.Designer.vb:line 62
>
> at Game_Save_Duplicator.Form1.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
> in D:! Random Work in progress\Game Save Duplicator\Game Save
> Duplicator\Form1.vb:line 12

How did i try to resolve this bug?:

I uninstalled the IDE and installed it hoping the dumb errors would go away as I think it has something to do with the IDE because....previous working programs that use my.settings also dont work now?

I reset my computer a second time and installed Visual studio for a third time but this bug still exists.

Comment: Does this happen just on your existing project(s) or new projects as well?  Have you tried removing the settings file and re-creating it from scratch?

Comment: Try deleting configuration files from 'c:\Users\username\AppData\Local\appname' and restart your application.

Comment: @Hursey ...it happens with mostly with new projects.....code and settings .settings work fine in previous projects....but if i duplicate that exactly into a new project it does not work

Comment: @XingyuZhao - this folder does not exist for me...well the project's name is 'Game Save Duplicator' and you are talking about a config file ?...I know where the project folder is located with the: Bin, My project, Obj, and everything else but I cant find a config file?